# SAS Selecting the most recent dataset in a lib automatically

Tags: sas

i am working with a library that is updated every month or so, and  i need a way to select the most recent dataset each month, i tried two methods that would show me the latest table, one that makes a table ordering from the modified date

```
proc sql;
   create table tables as
   select memname, modate
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname = 'SASHELP'
   order by modate desc;
quit;
```

and one that gives me just the latest modified one

```
proc sql;
   select memname into> latest_dataset
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname='WORK'
   having crdate=max(crate);
   %put &=latest_dataset;
```

and i would like to put these latest datasets in a table, but i don't know how, or if there is another easier way to do this, i am still very much new to SAS programming so i'm lost, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the goal to create a dataset, like your first query, or a macro variable you can use to generate SAS code, which your second query would do if the syntax was correct.

Comment: Do you want to put the name of the newest data set in a table or append the newest data to another table in a different library ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Proc APPEND` to *put the latest data set into a table*.  You are essentially accumulating rows.

Use `SQL` `:INTO` to obtain (place into a macro variable) the *`libname.memname`* of the data set that should be appended.

Example:

The task of determining the newest data set and appending it to a base table is also in a macro so the the code can be easily rerun in the example.

```
%macro append_newest;

%local newest_table;

proc sql noprint;
  select catx('.', libname, memname) into :newest_table
  from dictionary.tables 
  where libname = 'WORK' 
    and memtype = 'DATA'
  having crdate = max(crdate);

%put NOTE: &=newest_table;

  create view newest_view as 
  select "&newest_table" as row_source length=41, *
  from &newest_table
  ;

proc append base=work.master data=newest_view;
run;

%mend;


* create an empty for accumulating new observations;
data work.master;
  length row_source $41;
  set one (obs=0);
run;

data work.one;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name between 'A' and 'E';

%append_newest;

data work.two;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name between 'Q' and 'ZZ';

%append_newest;

data work.three;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name between 'E' and 'Q';

%append_newest;
```

Will produce this *master table* that accumulates the little pieces that come in day by day.

[image]

You would want additional constraints such as a unique key in order to prevent appending the same data more than once.